# Updated to ElCapitan, diasbled rootless to get mysql working but now get a 403 on phpmydamin

Tags: python, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, osx-elcapitan

I just very recently started developing, and all I use is a django/python setup. All projects were using mysql and working smoothly. Then I updated to osx 10.11 and got issues with the mysql server. After disabling rootless feature I was able to get projects running on the server. But I cannot get access to the phpmyadmin page. I tried adding a username.conf but that didn't work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your webserver error log say about the 403?

Comment: Hello, this is what I get in the error log:                                                        [Fri Oct 09 00:05:51.372774 2015] [autoindex:error] [pid 758] [client 127.0.0.1:51116] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpmyadmin/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive